# Bash date problem

Tags: bash

I'm running this bash script to make a backup of the database, but I'm always getting an error on the date and tar command.

```
#!/bin/bash
backup_filename=/var/www/vhosts/foo.com/private/backup_foo_db.sql
filename="db_daily_"`date +%Y%m%d`".tar.gz"
compressed_filename=/var/www/vhosts/foo.com/private/backup_foo_db_$filename.tar.gz
mysqldump --add-drop-table -h localhost -ufoo -pbar foobar > $backup_filename
tar cvfz $compressed_filename $backup_filename
rm $backup_filename
```

`./mysqlbackup.sh: line 3: date: command not found`

Could this be a permission problem? I'm not running that file as root.

Comment: Try specifying the full path: `/usr/bin/date`, `/usr/bin/tar`, etc

Comment: If you just want to compress a file, don't use tar, use something like bzip2 or gzip.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this as a cron job or something similar?  If so, the problem is likely that it's running with a different PATH than normal, and it doesn't include the directories that `date` and `tar` are in.  There are two easy ways to fix this: either use full paths for the commands (e.g. `/usr/bin/date`, as @glenn jackman suggested) or explicitly set PATH at the top of the script (e.g. `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin` or something similar).

BTW, you're also going to wind up with a weird backup filename. First, you set `filename` to something like "db_daily_20110926.tar.gz", then set `compressed_filename` to something like "/var/www/vhosts/foo.com/private/backup_foo_db_db_daily_20110926.tar.gz.tar.gz".  This is probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify and split this line into multiple lines, from:

```
filename="db_daily_"`date +%Y%m%d`".tar.gz"
```

So it becomes something like this:

```
myDate=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
filename="db_daily_"$myDate".tar.gz"
```

Comment: Or even nicer, `myDate=$(date +"%Y%m%d")`.

Comment: @KAK I think it is a matter of taste since they do the same, but you are right that the $() is maybe a little bit nicer.

Comment: You could even say `filename=$(date "+db_daily_%Y%m%d.tar.gz")` -- date's format string does not have to be just date fields.

Comment: @Johan, the `$(...)` syntax also has the advantage that it actually nests properly.